# Bug to display 10 as Card as Poker beta

Tags: poker-theory

Lets say if we have to Draw all 52 Card in the question answer we can only Draw 48 Card because the `10 in the all the color` . We can not Draw as Card.

see the below code with Draw Card :

**Heart Series :**

A♥, 2♥, 3♥, 4♥, 5♥, 6♥, 7♥, 8♥, 9♥, 10♥, J♥, Q♥, K♥.

**Clubs Series :**

A♣, 2♣, 3♣, 4♣, 5♣, 6♣, 7♣, 8♣, 9♣, 10♣, J♣, Q♣, K♣.

**Spades Series :**

A♠, 2♠, 3♠, 4♠, 5♠, 6♠, 7♠, 8♠, 9♠, 10♠, J♠, Q♠, K♠.

**Diamond Series :**

A⋄,2⋄, 3⋄, 4⋄, 5⋄, 6⋄, 7⋄, 8⋄, 9⋄, 10⋄, J⋄, Q⋄, K⋄.

As you can see the upper 52 Card we can only show 48 as a Card.
The Remain Card all 4 of `10` we can not display as Card to Draw as Picture as Other Card.

**Remain Card is :**

`10 of Spade` : 10♠

`10 of Heart` : 10♥

`10 of club` : 10♣

and `10 of diamond` : 10⋄

Other all are display fine.

**Update :**

If I ask on meta the Cards are display as below picture so I ask here. Because Asking on meta no one can detaect that this is bug.

**Image :**

[image]

Comment: Would this question be better suited (pun intended!) for [Poker Meta](http://meta.poker.stackexchange.com/)? Could potentially be combined with [the other question you have asked this morning](http://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/8472/short-cut-key-for-display-joker-in-the-question) - both relate to the mechanism for displaying certain cards in questions and answers.

Comment: @3N1GM4 you mean  I want to ask it on  `Poker Meta` ?

Comment: yes that's what I'm suggesting - seems more appropriate to Meta to me, but maybe someone with a longer history on this particular SE site can confirm?

Comment: @3N1GM4 see my update question..

Comment: I see the issue, I didn't realise the cards were not available on Meta - maybe someone can advise why and confirm where this question should reside?

Comment: I'm currently using the Android app and I can see the upper 3 suits just fine,  including the 10, but the diamonds display as boxes with an x in them.

Comment: I think even though this is a meta question, considering the nature of the bug it should be left here in the main Q&A.

Comment: @jon It is not even really a bug

Comment: Main admin isn't very responsive to this unfortunately. Seems like a simple fix, including a hand history converter, but there appears to be little will to resolve these issues despite them having been brought up in the past. Go straight to the higher ups if possible about this.

Comment: @TobyBooth It is not an issue or a bug.   They were using the wrong syntax.    This is not a hand history converter question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A♠ 2♠ 3♠ 4♠ 5♠ 6♠ 7♠ 8♠ 9♠ T♠ J♠ Q♠ K♠

You need to use a T

Comment: Thnx Instead of `10` I have to use `T`.